# Get dpi settings via GTK

Tags: gtk, screen, dpi

Using GTK, how do I query the current screen's dpi settings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current accepted answer is for PHPGTK, which feels a bit odd to me. The pure GDK library has this call: [gdk_screen_get_resolution()](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/stable/GdkScreen.html#gdk-screen-get-resolution), which sounds like a better match. Haven't worked with it myself, don't know if it's generally reliable.

Comment: That function returns resolution, or number of pixels.

DPI measures the assumed "dots per inch", or density of pixels.  Those are two entirely different concepts.

Comment: No, it does not, at least not according to the documentation. It returns a single double, which is "a scale factor between points specified in a PangoFontDescription and Cairo units. The default value is 96, meaning that a 10 point font will be 13 units high. (10 * 96. / 72. = 13.3)".

Comment: I stand 100% corrected.  And baffled by the function name.  Thank you, unwind.

Answer (score 1):

See [GdkScreen](http://gtk.php.net/manual/en/gdk.gdkscreen.php). You should be able to compute it using the `get_height` and `get_height_mm` or with `get_width` and `get_width_mm`.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution height and width returned by screen includes the full multi-monitor sizes (e.g. combined width and length of the displayer buffer used to render multi-monitor setup).  I've not check of the mm (millimeter width/height) calls returns the actual physical sizes but if it report combined physical sizes then the dpi computed from dividing one with another would be meaningless, e.g. to draw a box on screen that can be measured using a physical ruler.